# How do I import garment patterns into blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, add-on

I have created my garment patterns using Valentina(.val file) , now I want to import this into blender to make 3D simulations.

How can I do that?

Comment: What formats does this "Valentina" export to?

Comment: It exports to a .val file

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the patterns form the app you are using on some format that is [supported by blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/media/image_formats.html).

**Image**

JPEG, JPEG2000, PNG, TARGA, OpenEXR, DPX, Cineon, Radiance HDR, SGI Iris, TIFF

**[Video](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/media/video_formats.html)**

AVI, MPEG and Quicktime.

**3D**

Alembic, 3D Studio (3DS), COLLADA (DAE), Filmbox (FBX), Autodesk (DXF), Wavefront (OBJ), DirectX (x), Lightwave (LWO), Motion Capture (BVH), SVG, Stanford PLY, STL, VRML, VRML97, X3D.